# Databinding selected items in html select from asp.net

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, multi-select

I am coding in asp.net and I have added the html select control as seen below. I need to also databind some of the values to be pre-selected, how do I do that?

```
<select multiple="true" runat="server" id="SelectControlID" 
    datasource='<%# GetItems(Convert.ToInt64(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID"))) %>' 
    datatextfield='LocationName' datavaluefield='LocationID'>
</select>
```

Please note that I have to have runat="Server" as I need to retrieve the values in code behind. This means I cannot do something of the form below as that is not allowed with runat server.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" DataSource='SOMETHING'>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <option <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SelectedHTML") %> 
                value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LocationID") %>'>
                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LocationName") %>
        </option>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

In the end my requirements is a dropdown that allows multi select of items and being able to databind pre-selected items and retrieve its values on server side. I tried doing this with a select html control as above and using [jquery multiselect widget](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget). Please help me get the rest of the way or suggest an easy alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with the asp:repeater option and avoided runat="server" by instead doing

```
Request.Form["SelectControlID"]
```

This let me access the selected values while also setting pre-selected values on databind.

Remember to also set name attribute along with id on the select control to be able to find it from request form.